# CQRS clarifications - complex commands and handlers return types

Tags: .net, cqrs, mediatr

I'm developing a Web API to handle orders.
An Order is composed by several primitive properties and a **list of products**.
I'm learning the CQRS pattern and I'm using MediatR library.
I'm also using clean architecture.

Let's suppose I want to implement the action "add a new order".

How am I supposed to:

1. Build the command

I always see too simple examples in which commands are composed only by simple primitives.
In this case I've got a **list** (the products).
If I can just put the list of DTOs, why can't just wrap the entire request in the command?
Which is the best practice?

2. Handlers return types (for example in a "get order by id")

Consider that in clean architecture the application layer can't "see" the presentation one.
So I can't return DTOs.

I could return domain entities but then I will need to map them in the presentation layer.
To map them I need the presentation layer referencing the domain layer.

Any clarification about this would be appriciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are those established products with some sort of identifier on them, or are they truly dynamic and unique for every order? If it's the first one, then you probably don't actually need to be passing the products, just their IDs -- now you're back to a simpler command, something like:

```
public record CreateNewOrderWithProducts(int OrderNumber, IReadOnlyCollection<Guid> ProductIds);
```

You might, in that case, also have commands for `CreateNewProduct` or `UpdateProduct`, etc. You're containing just the information that is relevant to the action being taken, avoiding as much ambient coupling as possible; your command handler doesn't have any dependency on your input model or care that the command came from an API endpoint. If you opted to invoke the same command with say, a message bus event consumed from some other service by a different means totally unrelated to an HTTP request, you can do that just as easily.

If for whatever reason you really do need to contain the large amount of dynamic products in the command because they're made up and unique for every order, then you do: in this case, this remains a valid responsibility of the command being handled in creating an order because it has no relation to any other persisted entity. Even in the case above, you might logically have to include things like quantities, and if a simple shared model to convey those command-relevant requirements are necessary, then okay!

For your return type, you absolutely can be using DTOs from the shared contracts/interfaces in the middle. Your application layer may not be able to see the presentation one, but that doesn't mean that the inverse is not true: your presentation layer can include the logic to convert the shared contracts into the display/view models you want to return. I often handle this using custom static extension methods that accept an enumerable of my shared DTO so that I can take the result of a query handler and do something like `results.ToUiModels()` to return the result to the API. Likewise, the infrastructure layer does something similar, converting its own database models to/from the shared DTOs.